# C#: CSVReader.GetRecords Not Loading Any Records Even Though There Are Records in the CSV File

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to load a CSV file without a header using the CSVHelper nuget package 30.0.1. I have a CSV file with a single line. I load the CSV file using the CsvReader.GetRecords function. GetRecords returns no values even though there is an entry in the CSV file. It seems very simple but I haven't been able to figure out what is going wrong. I tried using the Index and HasHeaderRecord(false) attributes and setting CsvConfiguration.HeaderValidated to null but it continued to load zero records from the CSV file for the combinations I tried. Any idea why GetRecords would fail to read any records from the CSV?

CSV content:

```
Fred,Borscht
```

Simplified code follows:

```
[HasHeaderRecord(false)]
public class MyBizObject
{
 [Index(0)]
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 [Index(1)]
 public string LastName { get; set; }
}

CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csvConfig.HeaderValidated = null;
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(textReader, csvConfig))
{
  IEnumerable<MyBizObject> records = rdr.GetRecords<MyBizObject>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use attributes for configuration you need to either pass the type of the object into the constructor of the config, or call `CsvConfiguration.ApplyAttributes`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("Fred,Borscht\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeof(MyBizObject))
    {
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.GetRecords<MyBizObject>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

[HasHeaderRecord(false)]
public class MyBizObject
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

[image]